# Use Python for summing subset of columns in csv

Tags: python, csv, sum

I am trying to optimize some code to run faster.  For this text file matrix:

```
TAG, DESC, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, 
1, "details", 0, 1, NA, 1, 2
2, "details", 2, 1, NA, 0, 1
3, "details", 1, NA, NA, 0, 2
...
```

This is a large file with ~10,000 columns and ~2M rows.  What i would like to do is calculate the sum of across all ID's (4 for TAG=1) and the frequency given that the maximum value is 2 (so 4/8 = 0.5), and then append these values are new columns.  The NA's are missing data and effectively zeros.  This code works but it is very slow:

```
tab_dict =csv.DictReader(open(path), delimiter=",") 
tab_reader = [row for row in tab_dict]

for t in tab_reader:
    idlist = [i for i in t.keys()] 
    idlist.remove('TAG')  #exclude columns that do not contain numbers for summing
    idlist.remove('DESC')
    rowsum = 0
    for i in idlist:
        try: rowsum+= int(t[i]) #try/except to handle "NA"s
        except: TypeError
    t["ROWSUM"] = rowsum  # create the new columns
    t["ROWFREQ"] = float(rowsum)/ float(2*len(idlist))
```

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the point of reading the whole file into the `tab_reader` list so you can modify it as you go?  That's something you should avoid if at all possible.  Since the reader is an iterator, if your later processing doesn't require the whole file to be in memory it would be better to write the modified output line-by-line.

This version still uses a dictreader, but more built-in tools and should be faster:

```
ignored_keys = frozenset(('TAG', 'DESC'))   
desired_keys = [key for key in tab_dict.fieldnames if key not in ignored_keys]
frequency_divisor = float(2*len(desired_keys))
for t in tab_reader:
    rowsum = sum((int(t[key]) for key in desired_keys if t[key] != 'NA'))
    rowfreq = float(rowsum) / frequency_divisor
    t["ROWSUM"] = rowsum
    t["ROWFREQ"] = rowfreq
```

I think you'd see marginal additional improvements from using a `csv.reader` instance rather than `DictReader` and precomputing a list of desired indices instead of keys.  Or, of course, if 'TAG' and 'DESC' are always the first two:

```
   rowsum = sum((int(x) for x in t[2:] if x != 'NA'))
```

Comment: I was using the dictreader since this needs to flexible, and I will eventually need to read in csv files with more fields to ignore.  In my experience, header names are more stable than column order so I chose to access values as a dict

Comment: That's definitely true, but if you need to squeeze out every bit of performance it might be worth cutting out the overhead of creating a dict for every line in your file.  You can still be flexible by dynamically calculating the list of indices you care about.  It's less elegant, and I normally prefer the dict-oriented classes, but they do a little extra work for each row compared to the array oriented ones.  But the difference is probably small.  I think the single biggest speedups you can get are from getting rid of the 'remove' calls and if you can, from not creating the `tab_reader` list.

Answer (score 2):

For one, you loop through the data twice, once to create the tab_reader and the once to sum all values. Second, you might want to ditch your DictReader and simply loop though the file yourself. Also, using built-in functions will speed up.

```
from __future__ import division # to use float division

for line in open(path):
    ids = line.split(',')[2:]
    ids = [int(id) if id != 'NA' else 0 for id in ids]
    rowsum = sum(ids)
    rowfreq = rowsum / 2 * len(ids)
```

Comment: your method is very fast, but I will eventually read in CSVs with more DESC-like fields which need to be ignored for this calculation.  For this reason I am reluctant to hard-code any column numbers